# Get a JSON object key as a link

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get a json as a json format, but the keys as a link.

So that, Whenever i click on the link, I should get the output as key with an index

example

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio 
    reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et 
    cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt 
    rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor 
     beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil 
     molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi 
     nulla"
     }
     ]
```

When i click on userId where id is 1, I should get the otput as 0.userId

Can anyone suggest me a way to get a proper solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

okay if you are not using `jquery` try this out

```
url = Object.keys(jsonObject).map(function(someparameter) {
    return encodeURIComponent(someparameter) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(jsonBoject[someparameter])
}).join('&')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something like this https://json-ld.org/